# Playing a MP3 from a Python process's memory via omxplayer, without writing to disk

Tags: python, omxplayer

The following code receives an MP3, writes it to disk and plays it using OMXPlayer. I want to eliminate the need to write the MP3 to disk before playing it.

```
song = response.content
file = open("temp.mp3", "wb")
file.write(song)
file.close()
response.close()
play_song_subprocess = subprocess.call(['omxplayer', '-o', 'local', '--vol', '-500', 'temp.mp3'])
```

How can I eliminate the `file.write()`?
I'm looking to do something like this:

```
song = response.content
play_song_subprocess = subprocess.call(['omxplayer', '-o', 'local', '--vol', '-500', song])
```

But this causes the following error:
embedded null byte

Comment: So, for example: Try `cat file.mp3 | omxplayer -o local --vol -500 /dev/stdin`; if reading from `/dev/stdin` works, then we should be able to write Python that works too.

Comment: (The reason for that test is that a FIFO is _non-seekable_: It can only be read once, from beginning to end; one can't skip ahead, rewind, etc; not all software for manipulating media files can operate that way -- sometimes they expect to be able to read through the content in multiple passes, or jump ahead to a footer, or so forth).

Comment: (BTW, just to explain the "embedded null byte" error -- the command line consists of a list of C strings. C strings are terminated by the first NUL they contain; thus, you can't put data that contains any NULs inside of a command-line argument. And anyhow -- `omxplayer` is expecting anything in that position to be a _filename_, not to be data to be played; if it tries to open your data as if it were a filename, it's to be expected that you'd just end up with another error later).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you for the comment but subprocess.call() does not always require filesystem operations. For example: subprocess.call(['omxplayer', '-o', 'local', '--vol', '-500', 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/get_mp3_song_get']) work fine.

Comment: How do you think it finds `/usr/bin/omxplayer` without the filesystem?

Comment: song needs to be converted to the equivalent of temp.mp3 but without the disk I/O operation.

Comment: Yes, I know what you were getting at. That's why I told you to run the test with `/dev/stdin` [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63552681/how-to-play-mp3-using-omxplayer-without-disk-i-o-operation-in-python?noredirect=1#comment112379973_63552681) (and I'm anxiously awaiting a response to that test). But the point is that the original question title was asking for something that's in a pedantic sense impossible, and thus that a clearer title would improve things.

Comment: (BTW, if `/dev/stdin` and `/dev/fd/0` and `/proc/self/fd/0` aren't accepted, try using `-` as a placeholder for stdin in the filename position; it's not guaranteed to work, but it is a POSIX-standardized convention).

Comment: I don;t understand the purpose of the test. You would just call ```omxplayer -o local --vol 500 temp.mp3``` to play a local file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220333/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-mmclean).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Backstory For Readers

Established in chat and comments:

- `cat temp.mp3 | omxplayer -o local --vol -500 /dev/stdin` causes a segfault.
- `omxplayer -o local --vol -500 /dev/fd/3 3< <(cat temp.mp3)` works correctly.

Thus, we can pass a MP3's data in... but not on stdin (which `omxplayer` uses for controls: pausing, early exiting, etc).

---

#### Approach 1: Using A Shell For File Descriptor Wrangling

This is equivalent to "Approach 3", but instead of using very new and modern Python functionality to do the FD wrangling in-process, it launches a copy of `/bin/sh` to do the work (and consequently will work with much older Python releases).

```py
play_from_stdin_sh = '''
exec 3<&0                                     # copy stdin to FD 3
exec </dev/tty || exec </dev/null             # make stdin now be /dev/tty or /dev/null
exec omxplayer -o local --vol -500 /dev/fd/3  # play data from FD 3
'''
p = subprocess.Popen(['sh', '-c', play_from_stdin_sh], stdin=subprocess.POPEN)
p.communicate(song)  # passes data in "song" as stdin to the copy of sh
```

Because `omxplayer` expects to use stdin to get instructions from its user, we need to use a different file descriptor for passing in its contents. Thus, while we have the Python interpreter pass content on stdin, we then have a shell copy stdin to FD 3 and replace the original stdin with a handle or either `/dev/tty` or `/dev/null` before invoking `omxplayer`.

---

#### Approach 2: Using A Named Pipe

There's a little bit of a question as to whether this is cheating on the "no writing to disk" constraint. It doesn't write any of the MP3 data to disk, but it *does* create a filesystem object that both processes can open as a way to connect to each other, even though the data written to that object flows directly between the processes, without being written to disk.

```
import tempfile, os, os.path, shutil, subprocess

fifo_dir = None
try:
  fifo_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp('mp3-fifodir')
  fifo_name = os.path.join(fifo_dir, 'fifo.mp3')
  os.mkfifo(fifo_name)
  # now, we start omxplayer, and tell it to read from the FIFO
  # as long as it opens it in read mode, it should just hang until something opens
  # ...the write side of the FIFO, writes content to it, and then closes it.
  p = subprocess.Popen(['omxplayer', '-o', 'local', '--vol', '-500', fifo_name])
  # this doesn't actually write content to a file on disk! instead, it's written directly
  # ...to the omxplayer process's handle on the other side of the FIFO.
  fifo_fd = open(fifo_name, 'w')
  fifo_fd.write(song)
  fifo_fd.close()
  p.wait()
finally:
  shutil.rmtree(fifo_dir)
```

---

#### Approach 3: Using A `preexec_fn` In Python

We can implement the file descriptor wrangling that Approach 1 used a shell for in native Python using the `Popen` object's `preexec_fn` argument. Consider:

```
import os, subprocess

def move_stdin():
  os.dup2(0, 3)                       # copy our stdin -- FD 0 -- to FD 3
  try:
    newstdin = open('/dev/tty', 'r')  # open /dev/tty...
    os.dup2(newstdin.fileno(), 0)     # ...and attach it to FD 0.
  except IOError:
    newstdin = open('/dev/null', 'r') # Couldn't do that? Open /dev/null...
    os.dup2(newstdin.fileno(), 0)     # ...and attach it to FD 0.

p = subprocess.Popen(['omxplayer', '-o', 'local', '--vol', '-500', '/dev/fd/3'],
                     stdin=subprocess.PIPE, preexec_fn=move_stdin, pass_fds=[0,1,2,3])
p.communicate(song)
```